# Windows 10 Upgrade (Space)

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, ssd, windows-10-upgrade

I have tried to upgrade to windows 10 and I get the message "We can't tell if your PC has enough space to continue installing Windows 10.  Try Restarting Setup"  I have tried both the ISO and the USB boot disk.  I booted to the disk and it directed me to upgrade after starting my OS.

I have seen a few people saying that swapping SATA cables and making my OS disk 0 would fix it.  I did that with no avail.  I have ~100 gigs available (with only 20 being needed).

Any ideas

Comment: Have you moved any standard folder ( system, user, ect. ) from its normal location to another location?  If you have that can and will cause the upgrade to fail.

Comment: I have not.  It's a standard windows 8.1 install.  Nothing special.

Comment: Do you have `$Windows.~BT` and `$Windows.~WS` on your local disk?  Additionally, have you tried to perform the upgrade, directly using the tool itself instead of creating an .ISO?

Comment: I have the .BT folder.  It is created after I click update with about 2.6 gigs of info.  I have tried the standard upgrade (but it won't download as our GPO blocks MS updates).  We use an internal WSUS server and it won't download.  The jump drive I use is fine because I have upgraded a couple of other laptops with it.  It seems localized to 1 PC and I really don't want to format it.

Comment: Have you tried removing that folder.  The size of that folder should be at least twice as big.

Comment: Yes - multiple times.  I have removed, restarted, made sure all updates are installed.  Every time, the BT folder is put back with the same size.  It gets to where it checks for space requirements and fails stating it can't determine if I have enough space.